# Issue with ListView selected item color

Tags: android, listview

I've created a list view which shows some data. When the user clicks on a specific item, its color should change.

This works, except that every 10th item changes color, not just the item clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try add in your activity

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

this shloud make your selction single not multiaple selction